# How to create a new notebook without the value defined in a former notebook?

Tags: system

When I try to calculate sth new and create a new notebook, the variables in the former notebook will be a trouble. The only I know is use `Clear["*"]` or quit the kernel.

So do you know how to create a new notebook unrelated with the former one?

My MMA:
version: 11.20.0.0
platform: Mac Os X x86

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Choose contexts that are unique to each notebooks.  This has the added advantage that multiple notebooks open at once do not corrupt each other's variables.

Comment: I heard that there is an option can do this, but I didn't find the option. Can you tell me where is it?

Comment: @xzczd yes, it is exactly what i want